# How do I convert USFM to a Delimited file and vice-versa

Tags: windows, vb.net, dictionary

I am working on a personal project to speed up and automate some input features in a dictionary software I use. My dictionary project is practically ready, but I'm trying to find a way to convert the USFM records from the dictionary software to a delimited file using the semi-colon (;). I need this to be able to display the data in the Listview in my dictionary project. But after editing records in my project I then need to convert back to the original USFM format to export back to the dictionary software in order to make use of the Multi-Dictionary Formatting (MDF) tool to print the formatted dictionary.

**What I Have Tried**

So far, I have managed to open the USFM file (Sqlite DB file) as plain text in a textbox in my project as follows. But, although I have done a lot of Googling around all I can find is information about USFM and not how to work with it for conversion, etc.? I want to ignore the first two lines of the USFM/DB file to just display lexical records in my dictionary project's Listview, but when converting back to USFM/DB formatting these lines are probably necessary? Each record begins with '\lx' - lexeme and ends with a date stamp '\dt'. Not sure if this is the way to do this but it works for now?

**USFM SAMPLE**

```
    \_sh v3.0  400  MDF
\_DateStampHasFourDigitYear

\lx ahapei pyt
\ps sub
\ge Earring
\gn Brinco

\xv
\xe
\xn

\sd Artesanato

\dt 18/Apr/2023

\lx ahasep
\ps vb
\ge Extinguish (fire, lamp); Switch off (light)
\gn Apagar (fogueira, lamparina); Desligar (luz)

\xv
\xe
\xn

\dt 18/Apr/2023

\lx ahehay
\ps vb.
\ge Converse; Talk
\gn Falar; Conversar

\xv ahehay yn aiwyria'in wywo.
\xe we alway talk with our family/relatives.
\xn nós sempre falamos com nossos familiares/parentes.

\dt 03/Feb/2023

\lx ahek
\ps adj.
\ge Breathless
\gn Fôlego (sem)

\xv ase'i tuwepot'am yity'ok apypekiat kape hawyi sese i'ahek.
\xe after the older man/grandfather climbed up to the top of the hill
he was really breathless.
\xn depois que o homem mais velho/vovô subiu até o topo do morro
ele estava muito sem fôlego.

\cf imo'ahek

\dt 10/May/2023
```

**WHAT I NEED**

Some records may include more or less USFM markers than the sample. Some may have empty fields such as the example fields (xv, xe, xn) in the following sample. Empty fields can just use a semi-colon for data to be inserted into the correct Listview columns. Also, some of the lexemes are a single word and some use more than one word for a single lexeme.

Then, I need to convert from delimited format (i.e. csv) back to USFM format **unless there is some way to code for displaying USFM records** (same formatting as in the sample above) **in a Listview?** Maybe there is a way to do this *virtually* without needing to use a textbox?

The following is an example of the first record from the sample above *converted* manually to a delimited format. Then, I would need some way to identify the beginning and end of each record to insert each record as a new row into the Listview in my project?

\lx;ahapei pyt;ps;sub;\ge;Earring;\gn;Brinco;\xv;;\xe;;\xn;;\sd Artesanato;\dt 18/Apr/2023

Next record / Lexeme...

**CODE FOR OPENING USFM/DB FILE IN TEXTBOX**

```
Dim myStream As Stream = Nothing
    Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog()

    With ofd

        .InitialDirectory = "C:\Users\jmwil\Documents\Lexique Pro\Data"
        .Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        .FilterIndex = 2
        .RestoreDirectory = True

        If ofd.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Try
                myStream = ofd.OpenFile()
                If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then
                    ' Insert code to read the stream here.

                    'Open Selected Filename Into TextBox:
                    TextBox35.Text = ofd.FileName

                                            Dim fileReader As String
                    fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(ofd.FileName.ToString,
                       System.Text.Encoding.UTF32)
                    'MsgBox(fileReader)
                    TextBox36.Text = fileReader

                End If
            Catch Ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot read file from disk. Original error: " & Ex.Message)
            Finally
                ' Check this again, since we need to make sure we didn't throw an exception on open.
                If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then
                    myStream.Close()
                End If
            End Try
        End If

    End With
```

I would be really grateful for any help because I have a huge amount of data to work with and using the current dictionary software has taken literally many years to move my dictionary project forward! Another way of doing this would be if someone knows how to add MDF to my Windows Forms project in Visual Studio in order to have a fully-fledged, formatted dictionary output method? But I personally haven't managed to find out how to do that?

Comment: Not a direct answer I know, but there are quite a number of 3rd party tools and libraries around (nuget and vs marketplace) that seem to address USFM data formats.  Are any of these any use to you?

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Connect to a database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/add-new-connections?source=recommendations&view=vs-2022), [SQL Server Express LocalDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver16), and [Connection Strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-data-sqlclient/)

Comment: Thanks guys! I've been taking time looking around at some of that info. Never really worked with a database before so I'm starting from scratch on that! Not sure which 3rd party tools and libraries are out there or how to use them? I'll try an update as I go...